# Python process being killed due to out of 256Gb memory

Tags: python, machine-learning, memory, nlp, training-data

The training dataset is a 42GB JSON file. *mesh* is medical subject headings, consider it as an id or a label. neighbors_mesh is a 28,000 dimension list that has information about mesh that are close to each other. We got this data from training mesh terms for 1.07 M data through KNN. The MLB fit transform returns a 28,000-dimension vector of 0 and 1. But each element is int64 by default. I have tried to reduce it by `mask.astype(int__)`. It's still 32bit.

The iteration blocks 256GB of memory after running for about 1M iterations and still gets killed.

My python version is 3.9
The machine has 256GB memory, 20GB Swap memory, and 48 Core CPU, and GPU.

```
def build_dataset(train_path, neighbors, journal_mesh, MeSH_id_pair_file, index_dic):

    mapping_id = {}
    with open(MeSH_id_pair_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            (key, value) = line.split('=')
            mapping_id[key] = value.strip()

    meshIDs = list(mapping_id.values())
    meshIDs = label2index(meshIDs, index_dic)
    meshIDs_str = [str(x) for x in meshIDs]

    print('Total number of labels %d' % len(meshIDs_str))
    mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=meshIDs_str)
    mlb.fit(meshIDs_str)

    pmid_neighbors, neighbors_mesh = read_neighbors(neighbors, index_dic)

    f = open(train_path, encoding="utf8")
    objects = ijson.items(f, 'articles.item')
    

    dataset = []
    print("Objects: ", type(objects))
    print("pmid neighboors: ", type(pmid_neighbors))

    for i, obj in enumerate(tqdm(objects)):
        data_point = {}
        try:
            ids = obj["pmid"]
            heading = obj['title'].strip()
            heading = heading.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '[]'))
            abstract = obj["abstractText"].strip()
            clean_abstract = abstract.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '[]'))
            if len(heading) == 0 or heading == 'In process':
                print('paper ', ids, ' does not have title!')
                continue
            elif len(clean_abstract) == 0:
                print('paper ', ids, ' does not have abstract!')
                continue
            else:
                mesh_id = obj['mesh']
                journal = obj['journal']
                year = obj['year']
                mesh_from_journal = journal_mesh[journal]
                mesh_from_neighbors = []
                if i < len(pmid_neighbors) and ids == pmid_neighbors[i]:
                    mesh_from_neighbors = neighbors_mesh[i]
                mesh_from_journal_str = [str(x) for x in mesh_from_journal]
                mesh_from_neighbors_str = [str(x) for x in mesh_from_neighbors]
                mesh = list(set(mesh_from_journal_str + mesh_from_neighbors_str))
                mask = mlb.fit_transform([mesh])
                mask = mask.astype(np.int_)
                mask = mask.tolist()
                print("MEsh Size: ", sys.getsizeof(mask))
                print("Mesh content size: ", sys.getsizeof(mask[0][0]))
                print("Mesh content type: ", type(mask[0][0]))
                data_point['pmid'] = ids
                data_point['title'] = heading
                data_point['abstractText'] = clean_abstract
                data_point['meshID'] = mesh_id
                data_point['meshMask'] = mask
                data_point['year'] = year
                dataset.append(data_point)
                print("dataset Size: ", sys.getsizeof(dataset))
        

        except AttributeError:
            print(f'An exception occurred for pmid: {obj["pmid"].strip()}', AttributeError.args())


    pubmed = {'articles': dataset}
    return pubmed
```

Answer (score 0):

I successfully finished running the code by adding `f.close()` after the iteration is completed. The result is a 88GB dataset. But I am still curious why it's taking up so much space.